# How can I ignore any field of another class within one class?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data

I mean, for example I have ProductDTO and OrderDetail classes. I want to ignore price field on json because price is changeable and I want keep price for buy.
This is my ProductDTO:

```
public class ProductDTO {

    String id;
    String name;
    String description;
    int price; //I want to ignore this one
    String brand;
    String size;
    int stockCount;
    String type;
    String color;
    String gender;
}
```

And this is my OrderDetail class:

```
public class OrderDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    int price;
    ProductDTO productDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all,we never put a price in integer, it's a double or a bigDecimal.
secondly, we never put a DTO in an entity. DTO is a design pattern that allows data transfer without impacting the entity.

For your problem, it's a simple mapping point between DTO and entity. use a mapper either by manual method implementation or by using a mapper generated code like MapStruct.

For example you want to ignore the price like this :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProductMapper {
    
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "idDTO", target = "id"),
        @Mapping(source = "price", target = "price", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(source = "idArriveePar", target = "idArrivePar"),
    })
    Product toEntity(ProductDTO productDTO);
}
```

this would ignore the price as you want.

Hope this would be helpfull

Comment: *first of all,we never put a price in integer*. Nonsense. I have worked with many PoS syatems where prices are stored in base unit: cents, pennies etc.

Comment: and if we use different currencies? is this still valid? take the EURO to pennies, but for the Chinese or Japanese currency it is more ramiffer, of point is it fairer to have an externalization compared to the currency or in each case of figure to extend the classes ... ?
I think it is better to take the right base of trades as small as it is